# Is there a way to add location to the label of a marker that is randomly placed in google maps with javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Is it possible to add the LatLng to the label of the marker that is placed at random to show where that marker is? Also considering the infoWindow option but have not been successful yet.

```
var map;
var markers = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
var markersIndex = 0;

function initialize() {
    var Wilm = new google.maps.LatLng(34.2257,-77.9447);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: Wilm,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-
    canvas'),mapOptions);



    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
            addMarker(event.latLng);
    });


}

function addMarker(location) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        label: markers[markersIndex++ % markers.length],
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function(event) {
            marker.setMap(null);
    });

    markers.push(marker);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by a label.

this will add markers to the map with an info window with the latlng:

```
    function initMap() {
  var Wilm = new google.maps.LatLng(34.2257, -77.9447);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: Wilm,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
  });
}

function placeMarker(location) {


  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map
  });

  var contentString = 'Lat' + marker.getPosition().lat() + ', lng:  ' + marker.getPosition().lng();

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

```js
function initMap() {
  var Wilm = new google.maps.LatLng(34.2257, -77.9447);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: Wilm,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
  });
}

function placeMarker(location) {


  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map
  });

  var contentString = 'Lat' + marker.getPosition().lat() + ', lng:  ' + marker.getPosition().lng();

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&callback=initMap">


</script>
```

Comment: Thanks with some adjustments this was the info I needed.  @John is a code hero